# How to customize URLEmbeddedView in objective-c iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I'm using previews of every links. To do this I tried [URLEmbeddedView](https://github.com/marty-suzuki/URLEmbeddedView)
to add this url preview support. But this is giving me a view like

[image]

I need to customize this view like, the image should be go up and the text and other details should be placed below the image. Please help me to solve this layout issue.

Comment: That is nothing but a UIView with imageview and text. You can customise it as per your requirement!

Comment: I failed to find the exact place of UI components.. could you find the exact initializing code?

Comment: the link you mentioned has a class URLEmbeddedView, which contains the info you are aksing about.

Comment: You didn't search much. Found the relevant code in less than a minute.

Comment: imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        addLayoutSubview(imageView, andConstraints:
            imageView.Top,
            imageView.Left,
            imageView.Bottom
        )
I found.. But it's in Swift. I don't know how to customize that.

Comment: look for the imageView and uiview frame , and try to modify it.

Comment: @codebot are you able to install mentioned library using pod for the objective-c project? If yes, can you provide steps then it would be helpful?